# What crowdsourcing platforms are the most effective?

Tags: crowdsourcing

What crowdsourcing platforms are the most effective? and what measures have people used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effectiveness of a crowd-sourcing platform will mainly depend on the problem itself and how crowd-sourcing is applied to solve it.  A few well-known crowd-sourcing solutions include [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) and [CrowdFlower](http://crowdflower.com/).